# Task Scheduler Action parameter should generate log, but doesn't

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

As the title suggests, I have an added parameter in my Task Scheduler Actions that logs stdout and stderr to a log.txt file. The logging works when the action is run through the command prompt, but not when the action is run by the actual Task Scheduler (at its specified time). Task scheduler reports the action runs successfully, but I can't be sure it does because there's no logging:)

Command looks like this

```
powershell.exe -file "D:\Scripts\TimeSync2.ps1" > "D:\Scripts\timeSync_log.txt" 2>&1
```

I'm unfortunately not a native Windows user, so any help would be appreciated. I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you scheduling a batch file?  That would be the way to go.

Comment: Hi, the task scheduler has a number of bat and php scripts that are being executed on a schedule. Can you elaborate on your comment? The .bat files also don't log unless run manually on command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cmd.exe handles command redirection. You have to run it under cmd.exe. Powershell probably also can do redirection but in your script (.NET can).

A black window just means a console program is running. Only if cmd is running does cmd features become available. By starting cmd or by putting it in a batch you canget redirection from cmd.

```
cmd /c powershell.exe -file "D:\Scripts\TimeSync2.ps1" > "D:\Scripts\timeSync_log.txt" 2>&1
```

See for Help

```
cmd /?
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the command you listed in a batch file and then schedule the batch file.

If you are doing so and it fails, then try it with your account credentials as authentication in task scheduler, to see if it is a permissions issue.

```
@echo off
powershell.exe -file "D:\Scripts\TimeSync2.ps1" > "D:\Scripts\timeSync_log.txt" 2>&1
```